# Oracle PL/SQL Ref Cursor Function Missing Char

Tags: oracle, plsql, ref-cursor

When I run this code, the result should be 636790 but 63679 is only returned. Beating brains out on this one!!! Why the missing digit? Source table and column contain correct number of 636790.

```
create or replace package jt_types 
  as 
    type ttest is ref cursor;
end; 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jt_test
      RETURN jt_types.ttest
   IS
       o_return  jt_types.ttest;   
   BEGIN
           OPEN o_return FOR
               SELECT offn_id
               FROM jt_offn_4
              where offn_ID in (636790)
            ORDER BY offn_id;
     RETURN o_return;
  END jt_test;  

DECLARE
     l_ids                  jt_types.ttest;
     l_id                   NUMBER;   
BEGIN
    l_ids := jt_test;   
  LOOP
          FETCH l_ids INTO l_id;
          EXIT WHEN l_ids%NOTFOUND;
          dbms_output.put_line('Rec: ' || l_id);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_ids;
 END;
```

Comment: Why do I think that `jt_types.ttest` is something like `char(6)`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is to return sys_refcursor, here is the code:

```
create or replace 
function jt_test
      return sys_refcursor
   is
       o_return  sys_refcursor;   
   begin
           open o_return for
               select offn_id
               from jt_offn_4
              where offn_ID = 636790;
     return o_return;
  end jt_test;

declare
     l_ids                  sys_refcursor;
     l_id                   number;   
begin
  l_ids := jt_test;   
  loop
    fetch l_ids into l_id;
    dbms_output.put_line('Rec: ' || l_id);
    exit when l_ids%NOTFOUND;
  end loop;

  close l_ids;

 end;
```